# Product Order of Total Orders

Tags: order-theory

Given a product order $\langle X_1 \times X_2 \times ... \times X_p, \preceq\rangle$ of ordered sets $\langle X_1, \preceq^\ast \rangle$, $\langle X_2, \preceq^" \rangle$, ...

Is there a possibility to deduce whether these ordered sets ($\langle X_1, \preceq^\ast \rangle$, $\langle X_2, \preceq^" \rangle$, ...) are total orders from the properties of the product order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ and $B$ be ordered sets with $b$ in $B$, give $A\times B$ the product order and let $p:A\times B \to A$, $(x,y) \mapsto x$ be the first projection.
Show $p(A\times\{b\})$ is order isomorphic to $A$.

Thus knowing the product order, one knows the order of the components.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm looking for some sort of property which tells me right away if the ordered sets are totally ordered sets. If I have the totally ordered sets $X_1, X_2, ..., X_p$ and give the product order $X_1 \times X_2 \times ... \times X_p$. Is it fair to say if the width of the product order is $p$ then the ordered sets $X_1, X_2, ..., X_p$ are all totally ordered?

Comment: @andrestless. Does the sum of the widths equal the width of a not empty product?

Comment: @andrestless Suppose $X$ is the product of two two-element chains, and $Y$ is a one-element chain. In this situation, $X \times Y$ has width $2$, and you would conclude $X$ and $Y$ were chains, which is not the case. On the other hand, if $X$ and $Y$ are three-element chains, then $X\times Y$ has width $3$, and you would conclude that at least one of $X$ and $Y$ were not a chain, which they were. So that condition of yours is neither necessary nor sufficient.

Comment: @amrsa  Why is the width of the first X one?

Comment: @amrsa.  Prove the width of {0,1,2}×{0,1,2} is three.

Comment: @WilliamElliot The width of the first $X$ is two, so it's not a chain. The point is to claim that the condition andrestless was conjecturing doesn't hold. It's very easy to show that the product of two three-element chains is three; the three-element anti-chain in this product is $(0,2),(1,1),(2,0)$ and by eye inspection one can immediately tell there is no other anti-chain of size greater than two.

Comment: @amrsa.  As my conjecture is ruined, I'm done trying to prove it.

Comment: @WilliamElliot I really don't understand your last comment. It was andrestless' conjecture and it seemed to me that you were arguing with him (her) that it shouldn't hold. I think that your answer is not only correct (+1) but it is actually the best possible for this question...

Comment: @amrsa.  My conjecture is the second comment.